# Pyramids dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I encountered this question in an interview and could not figure it out. I believe it has a dynamic programming solution but it eludes me.

Given a number of bricks, output the total number of 2d pyramids possible, where a pyramid is defined as any structure where a row of bricks has strictly less bricks than the row below it. You do not have to use all the bricks.

A brick is simply a square, the number of bricks in a row is the only important bit of information.

Really stuck with this one, I thought it would be easy to solve each problem 1...n iteratively and sum. But coming up with the number of pyramids possible with exactly i bricks is evading me.

**example, n = 6**

```
X

XX

X
XX   XXX

X
XXX   XXXX

XX      X
XXX   XXXX   XXXXX

X
XX      XX       X
XXX   XXXX   XXXXX   XXXXXX
```

So the answer is 13 possible pyramids from 6  bricks.

**edit**

I am positive this is a dynamic programming problem, because it makes sense to (once you've determined the first row) simply look to the index in your memorized array of your remainder of bricks to see how many pyramids fit atop.

It also makes sense to consider bottom rows of width at least n/2 because we can't have more bricks atop than on the bottom row **EXCEPT** and this is where I lose it and my mind falls apart, in certain (few cases) you can I.e. N = 10

```
X
XX
XXX
XXXX
```

Now the bottom row has 4 but there are 6 left to place on top

But with n = 11 we cannot have a bottom row with less than n/2 bricks. There is another wierd inconsistency like that with n = 4 where we cannot have a bottom row of n/2 = 2 bricks.

Comment: If you don't have to use all of the bricks -- it is okay to use 0 bricks? So -- why not 14 legal pyramids for n = 6?

Comment: Not sure, I don't quite remember the problem statement that well, but I think it is better to limit the definition of a pyramid to at least one brick. Good call I didn't mention that in the problem statement.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect fit for a recursive function. For any combination/permutation problem I'd first consider recursion rather than dynamic programming.

Comment: Your statement "once you consider the first row, find out how many pyramids you can build on top" is a recursive statement

Comment: @slebetman yes, it is, and maybe I should focus on finding a recurrence first, however I am struggling with this task. It does seem viable to memoize the number of pyramids that can be built with exactly n bricks seeing how the answer to n = 1 comes up a lot in some of the higher numbers

Comment: Memoization is an optimization. Forget about it when you're still at the stage of designing the algorithm.

Comment: Okay, good point on how to approach problems like these thank you

Comment: Also known as `sum i = 1 to n of` https://oeis.org/A000009 `(i)` (1+1+2+2+3+4 = ?)

Comment: @גלעדברקן I'm having trouble reading this site, where is the series described?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's choose a suitable definition:

```
f(n, m) = # pyramids out of n bricks with base of size < m
```

The answer you are looking for now is (given that `N` is your input number of bricks):

```
f(N, N+1) - 1
```

Let's break that down:

- The first `N` is obvious: that's your number of bricks.
- Your bottom row will contain at most `N` bricks (because that's all you have), so `N+1` is a sufficient lower bound.
- Finally, the `- 1` is there because technically the empty pyramid is also a pyramid (and will thus be counted) but you exclude that from your solutions.

---

The base cases are simple:

```
f(n, 0) = 1   for any n >= 0
f(0, m) = 1   for any m >= 0
```

In both cases, it's the empty pyramid that we are counting here.

---

Now, all we need still is a recursive formula for the general case.

Let's assume we are given `n` and `m` and choose to have `i` bricks on the bottom layer. What can we place on top of this layer? A smaller pyramid, for which we have `n - i` bricks left and whose base has size `< i`. This is exactly `f(n - i, i)`.

What is the range for `i`? We can choose an empty row so `i >= 0`. Obviously, `i <= n` because we have only `n` bricks. But also, `i <= m - 1`, by definition of `m`.

This leads to the recursive expression:

```
f(n, m) = sum f(n - i, i) for 0 <= i <= min(n, m - 1)
```

---

You can compute `f` recursively, but using dynamic programming it will be faster of course. Storing the results matrix is straightforward though, so I leave that up to you.

---

Coming back to the original claim that `f(N, N+1)-1` is the answer you are looking for, it doesn't really matter which value to choose for `m` as long as it is `> N`. Based on the recursive formula it's easy to show that `f(N, N + 1) = f(N, N + k)` for every `k >= 1`:

```
f(N, N + k) = sum f(N - i, i) for 0 <= i <= min(N, N + k - 1)
            = sum f(N - i, i) for 0 <= i <= N
            = sum f(N - i, i) for 0 <= i <= min(N, N + 1 - 1)
```

Comment: f(n, n+1) doesn't make sense as the final answer. I think it should be f(x,y) where y should always be less than x, otherwise it will not be a pyramid.

Comment: @newbie_old did you read the explanation why `f(N, N+1)-1` is the answer?

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele I read and it says that it is sufficient upper bound but I just wanted to know if f(6,5) is enough for N=6?

Comment: @newbie_old by definition of `f`, `m` denotes the maximum size of the bottom layer. So `f(6, 5)` only allows pyramids with bottom `4` and smaller and thus does not count them all (it's missing the ones with a bottom of `5` and `6` blocks). `f(6, 7)` is enough, because it allows a pyramid with a bottom of `6` blocks. I added a paragraph to the answer showing that that is equivalent to `f(6, 8)`, `f(6, 9)`, and so on.

Comment: Ah, @newbie_old, only now I realized it said upper bound instead of lower bound. That explains your confusion

Answer (score 3):

In how many ways can you build a pyramid of width *n*? By putting any pyramid of width *n-1* or less anywhere atop the layer of *n* bricks. So if *p(n)* is the number of pyramids of width *n*, then *p(n) = sum [m=1 to n-1] (p(m) * c(n, m))*, where *c(n, m)* is the number of ways you can place a layer of width *m* atop a layer of width *n* (I trust that you can work that one out yourself).

This, however, doesn't place a limitation on the number of bricks. Generally, in DP, any resource limitation must be modeled as a separate dimension. So your problem is now *p(n, b)*: "How many pyramids can you build of width *n* with a total of *b* bricks"? In the recursive formula, for each possible way of building a smaller pyramid atop your current one, you need to refer to the correct amount of remaining bricks. I leave it as a challenge for you to work out the recursive formula; let me know if you need any hints.

Comment: I had not considered the width (bottom row) as a dimension. I was only thinking about n bricks being used exhaustively to create some pyramids. So for instance if n = 3, for i = 1 we have a lone brick as a pyramid, and for i = 2 we have a row of 2, and for i = 3 we have (3) and (2, 1). How can I use width as a restraint when depending on the number of bricks, the width could change?

Comment: I'm fairly confident that using all n bricks we can use k between n and n/2 bricks on the bottom row, although I'm not sure how to prove it. Then for each of those we add one + the number of pyramids we can build using n - k bricks on top of it. Right track?

Comment: @shane: I forgot to mention that, but indeed, you need to try all possible bottom layer widths and see which one gives the highest result.

Comment: So if I leave the width out of the recursion, then I can come close to p(b) = sum(0 <= k < b/2, p(b - k) + 1). Here I essentially iterate over all bases of at least b/2 and add that to the number of smaller pyramids I can put on top of it. But weird things happen when b = 4 as opposed to b = 6, where at 4 I can't have a base of b/2 = 2 but with 6 I can have a base of 3. I'm not sure if this is an anomaly and everything over 4 works, or the numbers have some property I'm not aware of.

Comment: @shane: You can't ignore the width, because you need to know the limitation on the width of the next level you'll build. Example: For _n=6_, it is valid to start out with a base width of 3, and for _n=7_, it is valid to start out with a base width of 4, and in both cases, you'll ask what you can build with _n=3_ remaining bricks. However, putting all 3 bricks in the same level is an option only if the level you're building on contains at least 4 blocks.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of your recursion as: given `x` bricks left where you used `n` bricks on last row, how many pyramids can you build. Now you can fill up rows from either top to bottom row or bottom to top row. I will explain the former case.
Here the recursion might look something like this (`left` is number of bricks left and `last` is number of bricks used on last row)

```
f(left,last)=sum (1+f(left-i,i)) for i in range [last+1,left] inclusive.
```

Since when you use `i` bricks on current row you will have `left-i` bricks left and `i` will be number of bricks used on this row.

Code:

```
int calc(int left, int last) {
    int total=0;
    if(left<=0) return 0;  // terminal case, no pyramid with no brick
    for(int i=last+1; i<=left; i++) {
        total+=1+calc(left-i,i);
    }
    return total;
}
```

I will leave it to you to implement `memoized` or `bottom-up dp` version. Also you may want to start from bottom row and fill up upper rows in pyramid.

Comment: Can you explain your chosen range?

Comment: Since you used last amount of bricks on last row you must use at least last+1 bricks on this row (since we are going from top to bottom), and you can have at most left count of bricks on this row since that's all the bricks you have left.

Comment: Deleted my comment, didn't realize we were going top to bottom

Answer (score 2):

Since we are asked to count pyramids of any cardinality less than or equal to `n`, we may consider each cardinality in turn (pyramids of 1 element, 2 elements, 3...etc.) and sum them up. But in how many different ways can we compose a pyramid from `k` elements? The same number as the count of distinct partitions of `k` (for example, for `k = 6`, we can have `(6), (1,5), (2,4), and (1,2,3)`). A generating function/recurrence for the count of distinct partitions is described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Odd_parts_and_distinct_parts) and a sequence at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000009).

Recurrence, based on the [Pentagonal number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem):

```
q(k) = ak + q(k − 1) + q(k − 2) − q(k − 5) − q(k − 7) + q(k − 12) + q(k − 15) − q(k − 22)...
  where ak is (−1)^(abs(m)) if k = 3*m^2 − m for some integer m and is 0 otherwise.

(The subtracted coefficients are generalized pentagonal numbers.)
```

Since the recurrence described in Wikipedia obliges the calculation of all preceding `q(n)`'s to arrive at a larger `q(n)`, we can simply sum the results along the way to obtain our result.

JavaScript code:

```js
function numPyramids(n){

  var distinctPartitions = [1,1],
      pentagonals = {},
      m = _m = 1,
      pentagonal_m = 2,
      result = 1;

  while (pentagonal_m / 2 <= n){
    pentagonals[pentagonal_m] = Math.abs(_m);
    m++;
    _m = m % 2 == 0 ? -m / 2 : Math.ceil(m / 2);
    pentagonal_m = _m * (3 * _m - 1);
  }

  for (var k=2; k<=n; k++){
    distinctPartitions[k] = pentagonals[k] ? Math.pow(-1,pentagonals[k]) : 0;
    var cs = [1,1,-1,-1],
        c = 0;
    for (var i in pentagonals){
      if (i / 2 > k)
        break;
      distinctPartitions[k] += cs[c]*distinctPartitions[k - i / 2];
      c = c == 3 ? 0 : c + 1;
    }
    result += distinctPartitions[k];
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(numPyramids(6)); // 13
```